# Conditional text color formatting in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do some conditional formatting in my views.

Please find the sample image for the reference.

[sample.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjQCE.jpg)

For "cash" it is working fine but i want to do it for "cash received", "credit note" and so on..

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <% balance = 0 %>

  <div class="table-responsive myTable">

    <table class="table listing text-center">
      <tr class="tr-head">
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Balance</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <% @statements.each do |statement| %>

      <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

        <td class="col-1"><%= statement.date %></td>

         <% color = (statement.description == "cash") ? "neg" : "pos" %>

        <td class="col-3 <%= color %>"><%= statement.description %></td>

        <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(statement.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

        <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

        <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


        <% balance += statement.amount.to_f - statement.discount.to_f - statement.paid.to_f %>

        <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

        <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

      </tr>

      <% end %>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is neg there? Is it red color?

Comment: Yes sir,.neg {
  color: #f00;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai You have taken the condition only for `cash`, so only its giving red, replace the `index.html.erb` with this.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

  <% balance = 0 %>

  <div class="table-responsive myTable">

    <table class="table listing text-center">
      <tr class="tr-head">
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Balance</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <% @statements.each do |statement| %>

      <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

        <td class="col-1"><%= statement.date %></td>

         <% color = (statement.description == "cash" || statement.description == "cash received" || statement.description == "credit note") ? "neg" : "pos" %>

        <td class="col-3 <%= color %>"><%= statement.description %></td>

        <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(statement.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

        <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

        <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(statement.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


        <% balance += statement.amount.to_f - statement.discount.to_f - statement.paid.to_f %>

        <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

        <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

      </tr>

      <% end %>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I do not want all the description values in red. I want the first value to be displayed in black as it is the invoice. waiting for your reply..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have more number of values as it is the statement that means number of invoices, number of payments...

Comment: How do you differentiate them?

Comment: Well, actually i want to look for the entries first, if the entry is the invoice for example SS16 as shown, then it must shown in black and on the other side if it is cash or cash received or credit note it must be in red color. Hope it helps..

Comment: You need red only if the values are Cash, cash recieved and credit note.Thats it?

Comment: Changed the answer please check.

Comment: No problem, please vote up if you are interested, :-), have a great day.